# How do I use Single Sign On for Wordpress and Java Spring?

Tags: spring, wordpress, authentication, oauth, openid

Let's say we have a site called *example.com*

Here, for example, I want to use some static content such as blog etc. and some pages in Wordpress. Wordpress build is using session-based authentication, with username and password strategy, also with third-party. (OAuth and OpenID).

I will design a custom and dynamic website section in Java Spring. And I want to use the same authentication mechanism with Wordpress.

For example, there is this path named *examle.com/test*. It is running from different server, which is based on Java Spring. But the session is shared with Wordpress. If there is a login from Wordpress (from *example.com*), it works on this server as well. Vice versa is also correct.

Login/logout should be possible from both Wordpress's pages and Java Spring's pages. Session must be shared. Wordpress already exists and the authentication mechanism is working. How can I use this in Java Spring? Or how can I do achieve this in some another way?

Answer (score 0):

If

- your Spring and WordPress apps are on the same top-level domain (for example https://spring.example.com and https://wordpress.example.com), and
- your Spring app can read rows from the wp_users table in your WordPress MySQL database, and
- your Spring app has access to the Authentication Unique Keys and Salts section of your wp-config.php file in your WordPress installation, and
- your users always log in to WordPress before they use your Spring app ...

Then you can use the `wordpress_logged_in_...` cookie to authenticate your WordPress users to your Spring app.  You'll have to rewrite the [wp_validate_auth_cookie()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/) in Java to do that.  Explaining how to do that is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

If any of those conditions aren't met you probably should explore some sort of federated login scheme. WordPress has [several SAML plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/SAML/). Spring also [supports SAML login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2).  Again, it's too big a topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Can I use JWT based authentication in Wordpress, also validate this token from Spring? Of course by knowing the private keys in both sides.

Comment: JWT is used to authenticate WordPress REST API operations.